# Google+ Sign In / Access Control List (Limit Who Can Sign In)

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I would like to use G+ sign-in to allow access to a secure area of a website.

However, I would like to only authenticate *certain* users. Either by

- Approving them after they request, or
- pre-defining a list.

Is this even viable?

Comment: it's viable but you'll have to write up your own code to deal with approval/whitelist on your server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Apache to serve the protected content or use Apache as a reverse proxy in front of the protected content, you could use mod_auth_openidc (https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc) and use Apache's `Require` syntax to configure the desired behaviour, see: https://github.com/pingidentity/mod_auth_openidc/wiki/Authorization